FPDF2 render_toc spans multiple pages it writes over page headers
Basically if my table of contents exceeds one-page then it the contents of the 2nd page overlaps with the document header.
I tried adding
self.set_y(15)

at the end of the header function. However this didn't help.
(Submitted the issue : here)

Hi. I am one of fpdf2 maintainers. You could report this on https://github.com/py-pdf/fpdf2. But please provide some minimal code reproducing your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

@LucasCimon I have reported the issue, do let me know if any further information is required.
https://github.com/py-pdf/fpdf2/issues/1336
